# Flask form not submitting but working under another scenario

Tags: python, html, flask, bootstrap-4, jinja2

I have flask website in progress, but the SubmitField is not doing anything whenever I click it.
I followed the similar method in submitting a much smaller form, it worked, but this is not working.

**routes.py**

```
from flask.scaffold import _matching_loader_thinks_module_is_package
from slotinfo import app
from flask import render_template,request,redirect
from slotinfo.models import Item
from slotinfo.models import Projects
from slotinfo.forms import AddProjectForm, ReserveSlotForm
from slotinfo import db
from slotinfo.models import Projects

@app.route('/') 
@app.route('/home')
def home_page():
    form = AddProjectForm()
    return render_template('home.html',form=form)


@app.route('/rack1')
def rack_one():
    items = Item.query.filter_by(rack_number=1)
    form = AddProjectForm()
    rform = ReserveSlotForm()

    return render_template('rack1.html',items=items,form=form,rform=rform)

@app.route('/rack2')
def rack_two():
    items2 = Item.query.filter_by(rack_number=2)
    form = AddProjectForm()
    return render_template('rack2.html',items=items2,form=form)

@app.route('/rack3')
def rack_three():
    items3 = Item.query.filter_by(rack_number=3)
    form = AddProjectForm()
    return render_template('rack3.html',items=items3,form=form)

@app.route('/witbe1')
def wit_rack1():
    items4 = Item.query.filter_by(rack_number=4)
    form = AddProjectForm()
    return render_template('rack4.html',items=items4,form=form)

@app.route('/addproject', methods=['GET','POST'])
def add_project():
    form = AddProjectForm()
    name=form.projectname
    name2 = request.form['projectname']
    x=Projects(projname=name2)
    db.session.add(x)
    db.session.commit()
    return redirect(request.referrer)

@app.route('/reserve',methods=['GET','POST'])
def reserve_r1():
    rform1=ReserveSlotForm()
    name = request.rform1['reserver_name']
    # if form1.validate_on_submit():
    #   name=form1.reserver_name
    print(name)
    return redirect(request.referrer)
```

In the above code, the rack1.html is the page where I am creating the form for submission. Also in the base.html , I used a smaller form it worked and its used in the function **add_project**(). But when I try to do the same for the rack1.html it does not submit anything. I use the function **reserve_r1()**

**rack1.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block title %}
  Rack 1 Page
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<br>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="jumbotron-fluid">
        <div class="card" id = "rack-table1" style="color: black;">
            <div class="card-header">
                <h3>Storm Rack One</h3>
            </div>

            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                        <h4 class="card-title">Details of the rack</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                        <button class="btn btn-outline btn-success float-right badge-pill" style="margin-left: 5px;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#reserveslot">Reserve</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-outline btn-danger float-right badge-pill" style="margin-bottom: 2px;">Release</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br>
                <table class="table table-hover table-light table-bordered" style="color: black;">
                    <thead style="text-align: center;">
                        <tr style="text-align: justify;">
                            <th scope="col" style="width: 8rem;">Rack Number</th>
                            <th scope="col" style="width: 8rem;">Slot Number</th>
                            <th scope="col" style="width: 10rem;">Project</th>
                            <th scope="col">Name</th>
                            <th scope="col" style="width:5rem;">Days</th>
                            <th scope="col" style="width:12rem;">Date of Reserving</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {% for item in items %}
                            <tr style="text-align: justify;">
                                <td>{{item.rack_number}}</td>
                                <td>{{item.slot_number}}</td>
                                <td>{{item.project}}</td>
                                <td>{{item.name}}</td>
                                <td>{{item.days_taken}}</td>
                                <td>NA</td>
                            </tr>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="reserveslot" class="modal fade" style="color: black;">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">  
              <!-- <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>   -->
              <h4 class="modal-title" style="text-align: left;">Reserve Slot</h4>  
            </div>  
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form method="POST" action = "{{url_for('reserve_r1')}}">
                    {{rform.rack_number.label()}}
                    {{rform.rack_number(class="form-control",placeholder="1-4")}}
                    {{rform.slot_number.label()}}
                    {{rform.slot_number(class="form-control",placeholder="1-4")}}
                    {{rform.project_Name.label()}}
                    {{rform.project_Name(class="form-control",placeholder="Project for reserving")}}
                    {{rform.reserver_name.label()}}
                    {{rform.reserver_name(class="form-control",placeholder="Who is reserving the slot ?")}}
                    {{rform.days_reserve.label()}}
                    {{rform.days_reserve(class="form-control",placeholder="For how many days ?")}}
                    {{rform.description.label()}}
                    {{rform.description(class="form-control",placeholder="Why do you need this slot ?")}}
                    {{rform.submit_slot(class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-primary") }}
                        <br>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer" style="text-align: center;">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" style="text-align: center;">Close</button>
            </div>           
          </div>  
        </div>  
      </div>  
</div>


<style>
.divider{
    width:7px;
    height:auto;
    display:inline-block;
}
</style>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the extra spaces around the `action` attribute.

```
<form method="POST" action="{{url_for('reserve_r1')}}">
```